# Bash command to delete a certain file in * folders

Tags: bash, .desktop

I have a `.desktop` file that execs with `bash -c` to set an environment variable then load the program. Now I need to add another command before it goes to loading the program.

Sometimes the program creates file called `SOFT_REPAIR` in `~/path to/*/`, and I need to delete it before running the program. `*` represents whatever version the program maybe, and as `/path to/` implies, there's spaces in the folder names within which the `SOFT_REPAIR` resides.

So here's the thing:

- Do I need to do `/path\ to/`?
- Will `rm 'path to/*/SOFT_REPAIR/'` work?
- Can I just use the `rm` command whether `SOFT_REPAIR` exists or not, or do I need to use the `if` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your original problem:

```
find ~/'path to'/ -name SOFT_REPAIR -exec rm -f "{}" \;
```

or, if you have GNU `find`:

```
find ~/'path to'/ -name SOFT_REPAIR -delete
```

To answer your questions:

- You need to backslash-escape the spaces in the file names if you don't wrap them in quotes.
- No, because the [quotes prevent shell glob expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion). This should work, though:

  ```
  rm 'path to'/*/SOFT_REPAIR/
  ```

  assuming that `SOFT_REPAIR` resides only two levels below `path to/`
- `rm` on a non-existent file will throw an error. `rm -f` will fail silently (at least in the GNU implementation of `rm`).

Comment: Deleting with the `find` command won't throw a tantrum if `SOFT_REPAIR` is non-existent, right?

Comment: Also, will `find` recursively  look into the subdirectories or do I need to specify exactly where the file is? If that is so, it defeats the purpose, because neither I nor the `.desktop` file will know the latest version of the program and subsequently the name of the folder with `SOFT_REPAIR` in it.

Comment: @Oxwivi `find` will not complain. It just applies the actions to any files it finds. Also, it operates recursively.

Comment: Trying it out answered my question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works. Simply use `rm -f path\ to/*/SOFT_REPAIR`.

But why don't you simply try yourself?

```
michas@lenny:~/t$ mkdir -p path\ to/{foo,bar}
michas@lenny:~/t$ touch path\ to/{foo,bar}/SOFT_REPAIR
michas@lenny:~/t$ tree
.
`-- path\ to
    |-- bar
    |   `-- SOFT_REPAIR
    `-- foo
        `-- SOFT_REPAIR

3 directories, 2 files
michas@lenny:~/t$ rm path\ to/*/SOFT_REPAIR
michas@lenny:~/t$ tree
.
`-- path\ to
    |-- bar
    `-- foo

3 directories, 0 files
michas@lenny:~/t$ rm path\ to/*/SOFT_REPAIR
rm: cannot remove 'path to/*/SOFT_REPAIR': No such file or directory
michas@lenny:~/t$ rm -f path\ to/*/SOFT_REPAIR
michas@lenny:~/t$ tree
.
`-- path\ to
    |-- bar
    `-- foo

3 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Unfortunately the alternative solution suggested by @Joseph suits the situation I described better. Sorry!